# Why is passive used here?

Tags: passive-voice

> 珍しいですね　聖さんがお酒を**飲まれる**なんて

Sei who normally doesn't drink gets angry and starts drinking a lot of wine. The speaker is a maid and she thinks Sei is happy instead and says that.

I would have used 飲む. I know お酒に飲まれる ([this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/94309/understanding-%E8%BB%8D%E6%9C%8D%E3%81%AB%E7%9D%80%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F)), but it doesn't seem to be a mistake.

The subject and the agent should be the same: 聖が(聖に)お酒を飲まれるなんて. Maybe, it's something like "You let yourself drink alcohol", but it's not causative. I've never seen this usage before.

Please, make similar examples.

Comment: Without more context, I can't be sure, but at first glance, this looks like a use of the passive form as honorific use.  I first heard this in real life in a taxi in Kyoto, when the driver asked us 「どこへ行【い】かれますか。」 No passive-ness intended, this was simply honorific use, as part of the driver showing politeness to us as customers and strangers.

Comment: In this context, '飲まれる' is an honorified form of '飲む'. '聖さんが酒を飲む' -> '聖さんがお酒を飲まれる'

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I've edited it. The speaker is in fact a maid. However, why didn't the taxi driver say どこへいらっしゃいますか? What's the difference?

Comment: "What's the difference?" → see [verbs which are more frequently used to built the honorific passive forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11533/32952)